# ClassNotFoundException: EnvironmentCapable

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Any suggestions how to resolve this Spring MVC error?

> Error configuring application listener of classError configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/env/EnvironmentCapable
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>               at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2733)
>
> //[redacted trace]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
>               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
>               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)

Comment: have you downloaded and added the org.springframework.core jar to the application's classpath?

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, it worked yesterday, but when I run today, it throws all error

Comment: ok let me ask you this, are all your org.springframework..... jars the same version number as this can cause compatibility issues? so as well as org.springframework.core you should also have org.springframework.context amongst other jars for a spring-based project

Comment: I had a similar issue,  I deleted the build folder in intellij project and re run the project, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Put the spring core framework (usually downloadable and has jar files) in your libs folder

Answer (score 0):

you have add into context loader classpath into web.xml.

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WordOfTheDay</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.do</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
```

Comment: I added it. Now it runs, but my jsp page turns out the blank.  I am calling string message from JSP, but it cannot to even print, so I put debug statements on JSP page before and after it. It print those statements,but it did not print the message. Can you help me out? If you need more information, please let me know, Thanks